# Error after organizing the current bundles in pimcore 10.6

Tags: symfony, pimcore, php-8.1

Im getting admin interface error after i migrated successfully pimcore 10.6, but admin interface not working.

when i printing echo its printing till render line but getting this error

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("None of the chained routers were able to generate route: Route '_profiler' not found

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue

im getting error in this line
$this->render('@PimcoreAdmin/Admin/Login/login.html.twig', $params);

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same issue, I fixed it by adding:

```
web_profiler:
  toolbar: false
  intercept_redirects: false
```

to `config/config.yaml`

This disables the web profiler completely.

Comment: you need to install symfony profiler, it will fix the issue